# Power Query - Split Column Error value cannot be null

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a column which starts with 2 number digits and then letters.
I'd like to split this into the number bit and the characters bit.

When I do:

```
    = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column","FamilyCode - Copy",Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 2}, false),{"FamilyCode - Copy.1", "FamilyCode - Copy.2"})

I get an error:

> Unexpected error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
Details:
    Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source ---> Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Odbc.OdbcQuery.AddColumns(ColumnsConstructor columnGenerator)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.Optimize(Query query)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.Query.QueryTableValue.get_OptimizedQuery()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.Query.QueryTableValue.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.TableValue.Microsoft.Mashup.Engine.Interface.ITableValue.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.ValuePreviewValueSource.TableValuePreviewValueSource.SerializeRows(Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.ValuePreviewValueSource.TableValuePreviewValueSource.get_SmallValue()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunStub>b__3()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.<>c__DisplayClass7.<TryReportException>b__6()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Common.SafeExceptions.IgnoreSafeExceptions(IHostTrace trace, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.TryReportException(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.RunStub(IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Func`1 getPreviewValueSource)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.<>c__DisplayClass32`1.<OnBeginGetResult>b__2f()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetResult[T](IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetResultMessage message, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetPreviewValueSource(IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetPreviewValueSourceMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.OnMessageWithUnknownChannel(IMessageChannel baseChannel, MessageWithUnknownChannel messageWithUnknownChannel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Run(Object args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass15.<CreateAction>b__14(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.SafeRun(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Main(String[] args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.OnException(IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, ExceptionMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.IMessageChannelExtensions.WaitFor[T](IMessageChannel channel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.WaitFor(Func`1 condition, Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.get_SmallValue()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Analysis.PackageDocumentAnalysisInfo.PackagePartitionAnalysisInfo.SetPreviewValue(EvaluationResult2`1 result, Func`1 getStaleSince, Func`1 getSampled
```

I double checked the column, each row has an entry, no empty rows and no rows with less than two characters (all min 5 to 10)

Anyone any idea?

Excel 2016

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more robust method that doesn't care how many digits are at the beginning of each string (can be none):

Remove your Duplicated Column step.

Then add a Custom Column named FamilyCode Number

`= Text.SplitAny( Text.Lower ( [FamilyCode] ) , Text.Combine ( {"a".."z"} ) ){0})`

Then add another Custom Column to get the Text part of [FamilyCode]

`= Text.End ( Text.From ( [FamilyCode] ) , Text.Length( [FamilyCode] ) - Text.Length ( [FamilyCode Number] ) )`

Hat tip to Ken Puls who blogged about this here:

http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/12/02/separate-values-and-text-part-2/